# How to Change CSS depending on browser width

Tags: javascript, css

I know how to choose one of alternate css according to browser width with css media property but.. what if I have to choose few of many alternate CSS...?

Suppose I have three themes on my webpage viz Red Green and Blue. Each of them have two variants _big and _small for browser width greater than 1024px and lower than 1024px respectively. So I have

- Red_big.css
- Red_small.css
- Green_big.css
- Green_small.css
- Blue_big.css
- Blue_small.css

Now I have three buttons to switch them. BtnR, BtnG, BtnB.
When I click BtnR, it switches the style according to browser-width ie if browser width is grewater than 1024px, then CSS selected is Red_big.css else Red_small.css...
and.. so on when I click BtnG or BtnB...

How to do that with javascript? Thanks.

Comment: Why not put the small version in a media query within the big one?

Comment: why don't you just group the css for big/small into 1 file and switch the colour css accordingly. Like red.css will have both big/small so all you need to do is switch the colour and the css will kick in based on width

Answer (score 3):

make it one big CSS file, and use responsive inside:

```
<style  type="text/css">
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    /* your css of 1024 px screen size */
    .green {font-size:40px}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 640px) {
    /* your css of 640 px screen size */
    .green {font-size:20px}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok try responsive css for example

```
min-width: 100%
```

this way the width will adjust with what ever the screen size maybe 
hope this helps.